# NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key rejected by iTunesConnect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios10

I have placed this key in my project's info.plist.
I have tried using a regular string and a string with no spaces for the value of this key. I have saved the info.plist before archiving.
I am still getting an error email froDear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "APP". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: if you have included this key with a description, include that and a screen shot of it in review comments.  Let Apple know the problem and that you have fixed it and they might give you further information on what to fix or just approve your app

Comment: This is an automated rejection email happening and I can't even seen the app in ITC

Comment: Did you try to do a clean> build and submit?